# ¿Cómo puedo ejecutar varias sentencias de sql en php?

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Me gustaría poder eliminar un id y a su vez hacer que se reinicie el auto increment con una sola "acción?" (soy bastante nuevo en esto, espero que comprendan)

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'php_login_database');
$sql = "DELETE FROM users WHERE users.id = 1;
SET @autoid :=0;
UPDATE users\n
SET id= @autoid := (@autoid+1);
ALTER TABLE users AUTO_increment = 1;";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result){
    header("Location: registros.php");
}else{
    echo "Error al eliminar";
}

?>
```

Comment: En un esquema de BD relacional, una vez la tabla tiene datos, no se debe reiniciar el autoincrementador porque si hay otras tablas, se rompería la lógica entidad-relación. Y de todas formas [la documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) dice: *You cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal to the value that is currently in use...*. En pocas palabras, no se puede asi. Tendrías que hacer un TRUNCATE y volver a llenar la tabla. Acostúmbrate a ver esos faltantes en la columna autoincremental ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza el método [multi_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.multi-query.php) sutituyendo tu línea

```
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

por

```
$result=$conn->multi_query($sql);
```

Para pasar de los resultados de una query a otra utilizas

```
$result->next_result();
```

Así como los métodos: `store_result()` y `free()`, además del `fecth_assoc()`.

Prueba, y si no te funciona, muéstranos el código que has intentado y el mensaje de error que obtienes.